# Nullable DateTime does not have methods to parse DateTime

Tags: c#, nullable

I am attempting to use nullable types but I am not sure if I am messing something up.

I have a method that accepts a DateTime parameter and then returns a string of XML with the `DateTime` specially formatted.

I find that if I change the method to try and pass in a `nullable DateTime` the compiler gives an error indicating that the methods used to separate out the `DateTime` components are not present (like `.Month` and `.Year`and `.Day`). I want to be able to pass in a `nullable DateTime` because the "theDate" parameter may be null. I check for `null` inside the method but it seems as the compiler is treating the `nullable type` as a completely separate `type` instead of a `DateTime type` that can also be `null`.

```
private static string CreateSpecialFormattedDateXml(DateTime? theDate)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  if (theDate != null)
  {
    sb.Append(CreateFieldNodeXml("year", theDate.Year.ToString()));
    sb.Append(CreateFieldNodeXml("month", theDate.Month.ToString()));
    sb.Append(CreateFieldNodeXml("day", theDate.Day.ToString()));
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}

private static string CreateFieldNodeXml(string fieldname, string fieldValue)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldValue))
  {
    return "<" + fieldname + ">" + fieldValue + "</" + fieldname + ">";
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: One option is `theDate.Value.Year.ToString()` etc.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks! that does indeed solve the issue. Could you explain more why this works and perhaps add it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types) cover it in great detail. I expect that someone with better duplicate-finding skills than I possess will come along and close this as a duplicate at some point soon so I won't post an answer here.

Comment: Basically as @KirkLarkin said: read the docs, don't assume the compiler is wrong

Comment: I will _try_, in English: It's the _underlying `value`_ (in your case `DateTime`) you want instead of `System.Nullable`. Hth....

Comment: Please use real xml building methods that will handle escaping

Comment: @webworm A nullable type in C# is a new type ```Nullable<T>``` which is not the same as a standard ```DateTime``` value type.  ```DateTime?``` is the same as passing ```Nullable<DateTime>```.  The ```Nullable<T>``` has overridden equality operators that allow it to compare as ```null``` with things like ```theDate == null``` but it cannot infer the hosted type for parameter swapping.  For you're method you need to do this ```if (theDate.HasValue) var dateTime = theDate.Value;``` Then use ```dateTime``` inside the method.

Comment: I've added a C# feature request based on this question.  It gave me an idea for deault value operators.  Take a look and share your thoughts. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2087